# How to detect a refuse to send SMTP response?

Tags: perl, email, google-apps

We are using a Perl program to send email using the [`Net::SMTP::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::SSL) module. We are also using the Google SMTP server. They have a limit of 100 emails per day sent via SMTP (if you are using the free service).

Occasionally we accidentally exceed that limit and Google does not send the email. But our Perl program does not seem to pick that up. Does anyone know how to detect the failure to send?

I think this is the relevant code:

```
use Net::SMTP::SSL;

my $smtp;

$smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new( 'smtp.gmail.com', Port => 465, Debug => 0 ) or
        die "Could not connect to Gmail server!";

$smtp->auth( $L, $P ) or die "Authentication Failed!";
$smtp->mail( $from . "\n" )  or die "Cannot send as user $from!";
$smtp->to( $to . "\n" ) or die "Cannot send to $to!";

$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend( "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" );
$smtp->datasend( "From: " . $from . "\n" );
$smtp->datasend( "To: " . $to . "\n" );
$smtp->datasend( "Subject: " . $subject . "\n" );
$smtp->datasend( "\n");
$smtp->datasend( $body . "\n" );
$smtp->dataend();
$smtp->quit;
```

Comment: All that `warn's` surely output something?

Comment: Can you use `Return` and/or 'Envelope` parameters to `mail` command for Delivery Status Notification? ([`Net::SMTP`](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/libnet-3.08/lib/Net/SMTP.pm))

Comment: A bit hard to read.  Could you reformat.  Try if/elsif/else.  if + not = unless

Comment: Reformatting your code reveals that, despite checking the from and to addresses, you still go ahead and try to send the email even if they are invalid. All that nesting of `if` statements is unnecessary

Comment: Yes, sorry, the code was just to indicate how we were looking for problems. None of the warnings happen. The attempt to send the mail does not trigger any warnings or errors, but the mail is not sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how exactly google rejects the delivery of emails if the limit is reached but there are a few ways:

- reject mail from or rcpt to commands: in this case you should see the warnings in your code
- reject the mail delivery: in this case `dataend()` should tell you the problem, i.e. the last method which should be called when sending the mail. But it looks like you don't even use `dataend()` in your code which might result in the delivery being pure luck anyway.

Comment: Thankyou, I have added the missing two bottom lines to the example - they are in our active code. I did not have a test on the dataend() statement. So I will try that. Unfortunately it is hard to replicate, so it may be a day or two before I can confirm your suggestion worked.

Comment: Yes the test on the dataend() statement works. Thank you.